# How does mysql indexes turn random I/O into sequential I/O

Tags: mysql, indexing

the [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do) says that one of the benefit of index is "Indexes turn random I/O into sequential I/O", so I don't understand how does mysql indexes turn random I/O into sequential I/O.

Comment: What is 'High Performance MySQL'? A book? Blog? Proper citation please.

Comment: a book, written by y Baron Schwartz, Peter Zaitsev, Vadim Tkachenko, see the link, http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do

Comment: Which of the 3 Editions is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean that when you have such indexes column in the table you can sort your stuff very easy as the indexes are a sequence

Comment: Three main benefits proceed from these
properties:
1. Indexes reduce the amount of data the server has to examine.
2. Indexes help the server avoid sorting and temporary tables.
3. Indexes turn random I/O into sequential I/O...
So, the sort benefit has been proposed, but still there is a "Indexes turn random I/O into sequential I/O" benefit, I really do not understand how. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Think of a telephone book. Suppose you want to look up people with last name starting with "S". You can find all of them very close together.

Sorting is also helped by using an index. If you search for all the people with last names starting with "S" and you want them in order by last name, that's no problem, the query can read them in the same order they are listed in the phone book, and they're all stored together. So the fetching is done by reading sequentially.

But if you want them sorted by something else, like their first name, there has to be some additional step of sorting the fetched rows before returning them in the order you wanted. The dataset you want to be sorted might be larger than can fit in memory, so it must use temporary disk space to do the sorting. There are ways to do this pretty efficiently, but it could require multiple passes, or building a sorted list as it fetches the rows from the database.

Basically, having the rows stored in pre-sorted order makes it efficient to search for values that are stored together, and efficient to retrieve them in the order of the index.

Comment: "indexes turn random I/O into sequential I/O", does it mean this only works for primary key? Since you can not store the data by two indexes order, when you fetch data by other indexes, you still have to go random I/O. Hope for your reply! Many Thanks!

Comment: I agree with that. Unless your query is an "index-only" query where it needs only the columns that are part of the index you are scanning.